# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I'm using sliding menu. it runs just a single time. when i come back to the fragment the app got crash. When my app will start it will show google map but through slider navigation i change my viw.Then when i came to the same view of Google map it got crash.

This is my logcat:

```
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment 
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-23 02:53:09.775: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

Here is my fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;


public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vaccinationmap, container, false);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        double latitude = 29.4000;
        double longitude = 69.1833;
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(4).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}


}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >"
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMyMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="My Map" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGlobal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="Global Map" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML file?

Comment: Also post more of the stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Comment: Additionally, please include your build.gradle file. I think I'm having the same issue, only with Android TV Leanback stuff, not maps.